# using winstonjs with external transports

Tags: node.js, logging, express, winston

The problem is that when I call the logger from an export function inside a controller called by http it only works with local strategies, slack and sentry never get notified.

the logger setup is something like:

server.js

```
//...
winston = require('winston'),
Sentry = require('winston-sentry'),
slack = require('winston-slack').Slack,
winstonMongodb = require('winston-mongodb').MongoDB;

global.log = new (winston.Logger)({
    transports: [
        new (winston.transports.Console)({
            handleExceptions: true,
            prettyPrint: true,
            colorize: true,
        }),
        new (winston.transports.File)({ 
            filename: 'logs.log', 
            json: true,
            handleExceptions: true 
        }),
        new Sentry({
            dsn: "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX",
            patchGlobal: true,
        }),
        new slack({
            domain: "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX",
            apiToken: "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX",
            channel: "#XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX",
            username: "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX",
            handleExceptions : true
        }),
        new(winston.transports.MongoDB)({
            dbUri: 'mongodb://XXXXXX:XXXXXXXX@XXXXXX.mongohq.com:XXXXXX/XXXXXX'
        })
    ],
}); 
//...
```

(I saw no example using a global var and if it's not a good idea let me know, but like this it works in all files without having to import.)

test controller:

test.js

```
//...
//called on server starts
log.info('test') //works with all transports

//called later by an HTTP request
exports.test = function(req, res, next){
    log.info('test') //only works with local transports (console and file)
}
//...
```

Answer (score 0):

Using globals should be avoided where is possible as it is in this case. Instead of using the global "log" you could use a singleton instead as follows:

```
var winston = require('winston');

var LoggerSingle = (function () {       
    var instance = null;    

    function Logger () {};

    Logger.prototype = new (winston.Logger)({
                                transports: [...]
    });

    return {
        getInstance: function () {
            if (instance === null)
                instance = new Logger();
            return instance;
        }
    };      
})();       

exports.single = function () {
    return LoggerSingle.getInstance();
};
```